# How to play an animation when an item is selected in the CollectionView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following CollectionView:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Brands}" Margin="5, 0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <pv:PancakeView Margin="0,0,0,10" Padding="10" CornerRadius="45">
        <pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
        </pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>

        <pv:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
          <pv:GradientStopCollection>
            <pv:GradientStop Color="#4166f5" Offset="0.0" />
            <pv:GradientStop Color="#1e90ff" Offset="1.0" />
          </pv:GradientStopCollection>
        </pv:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>

        <Frame Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
          CornerRadius="45">
          <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding image}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        </Frame>
      </pv:PancakeView>
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

I decided that animating the selected item would be cool, so I added a TapGestureRecognizer.
The event, which it points to, simply scales the PancakeView down and then scales it up.

After finishing that I bound the SelectedItem and SelectionChangedCommand of the CollectionView

```xml
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBrand}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding BrandSelected}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
```

Then, I came to understand that the TapGestureRecognizer blocks the CollectionView's Clicked event.

How can I animate the SelectedItem's PancakeView without blocking the SelectionChangedCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had used MVVM , you could handle the logic in ViewModel directly .

#### 1. Define a subclass of PancakeView

```
public class MyPancakeView: PancakeView
{

    public static BindableProperty IndexProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Index), typeof(int), typeof(PancakeView));

    public int Index
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(IndexProperty);
        set => SetValue(IndexProperty, value);
    }

    public MyPancakeView()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, int>(this,"tap",(org,id)=> { 
        
            if(id==this.Index)
            {
                // set  animation here
            }


        });
    }


}
```

#### 2. Add a property ID in your model of ItemsSource .

```
public class YourModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   
  // other properties
}

And set it as the index of ItemSource (0,1,2...)
```

#### 3. In xaml

```
<local:MyPancakeView Index="{Binding Id}" > 
 
   //...
  
</local:MyPancakeView>
```

#### 4. in ViewModel

in the set method of SelectedBrand

```
  public YourModel SelectedBrand
    {
        get
        {
            return xxx;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value!=xxx)
            {
                xxx = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBrand");
                MessagingCenter.Send<Object, int>(this,"tap", SelectedBrand.Id);
            }
        }
    }
```