# Why doesn't frame change its background?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a **CollectionView** on the homepage. The **CollectionView** element consists of a **Frame** as a container and other elements (see the code below). I want to implement **changing the color** of the **Frame** when it is **selected** in **collectionView**, but **VisualStateManager** "does not work". And how in this approach can I add **Frame animation** when I select it?

My ContentPage.Resources code:

```xml
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

My CollectionView code:

```xml
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame Margin="10, 10, 10, 0"
                           HeightRequest="100"
                           MinimumHeightRequest="95"
                           Padding="13" 
                           CornerRadius="20"
                           BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
                           BorderColor="Transparent">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Title}"
                                FontSize="19" 
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Label 
                                Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Text="{Binding Description}"
                                FontSize="16" 
                                TextColor="White"/>
                            <Label 
                                Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Text="{Binding CreationTime, Converter={converters:TimePrettifyerConverter}}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                TextColor="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Hello, here is a demo using MVVM pattern. Each time I click the button, a new Item will be added (see the gif below).

This is my **MainPage.xaml** file. Much similar to your code but with a Border instead of a Frame. A button is placed at the bottom to add new Item.

```
<StackLayout>      
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" HeightRequest="600">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border  Margin="10, 10, 10, 0"
                        HeightRequest="100"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="95"
                        Padding="13"
                        Stroke="Transparent">
                            <Border.StrokeShape>
                                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"/>
                            </Border.StrokeShape>                     
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                            FontSize="19" 
                            TextColor="White"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label 
                            Margin="0, 2, 0, 0"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Text="{Binding Description}"
                            FontSize="16" 
                            TextColor="White"/>
                        <Label 
                            Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Text="{Binding CreationTime}"
                            FontSize="12"
                            TextColor="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

    <Button Text="click me" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"   />
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the code for **MainPageViewModel** in which I define a **ItemCollection** property that CollectionView ItemsSource binds to. There is a ClickCommand for the button. Each time I click the button, a new item will be added to the CollectionView.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemCollection { get; set; }= new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    // each time i clicked the button, ClickCommand will execute to add a new item
    public Command ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                int n = ItemCollection.Count + 1;
                ItemCollection.Add(new Item
                {
                    Title = "Title" + n.ToString(),
                    CreationTime = "CreationTime" + n.ToString()
                });
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the gif I captured:

[image]

================== Origin Answer ================

That because you set the Frame BackgroundColor in DataTemplate. So we'd better not set the Property in any other places if we use VisualState in Resources. For a workaround, maybe you could set a normal state (this time we use **Border**):

```
<Style TargetType="Border"> 
......
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" >
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DodgerBlue" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
```

And use Border instead of Frame:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border  Margin="10, 10, 10, 0"
                HeightRequest="100"
                MinimumHeightRequest="95"
                Padding="13"
                Stroke="Transparent">
                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"/>
                    </Border.StrokeShape>                     
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Do you know how to add animation when clicking on a collection item? Maybe we should use EventTrigger or something like that? Does Frame have a "click" event (mobile app)

Comment: I found a similar issue here : [How to play an animation when an item is selected in the CollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311691/how-to-play-an-animation-when-an-item-is-selected-in-the-collectionview)

Comment: According to above issue, a custom control should be created. And when tap the item, the custom control can receive a message and show the animation.

Comment: Your answer works fine if the child element of the DateTemplate is a Grid (just like in the Microsoft documentation). But when I set the Frame as a first-level container, selecting items from the collectionView doesn't work. It feels like the Frame doesn't support the Selected state...

Comment: It feels as if collectionView contains its own container that you can click on. But for some reason, Grid does not "overlap" this container, and Frame "overlaps"

Comment: I could just use Grid, but I need rounded edges that Frame supports.

Comment: @luvairo That seems an issue for Frame in Android.  You could try using a Border instead of Frame. I have updated my answer please have a try.

Comment: Border "works", but now, for some reason, after adding a new element to collectionView, a random element becomes selected (I do not operate in any way with properties like SelectedItem, etc.). Also, now only the first element changes its color when selected, while the rest do not react in any way (however, when clicking on them, the focus from the first element goes away)

Comment: @luvairo I made a new demo with a button to add new item in the CollectionView. It worked well on my side. Please have a try.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. It turned out that List.Insert() causes incorrect behavior of the program. List.Add() works stably. I have no idea why this is happening))

Comment: I recommend to use a [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0). Then we don't have to raise propertychanged to refresh UI each time we add or remove an item in Collection.